# Kubernetes Future Release Schedule

Tags: kubernetes, release

I was tasked with finding out if Kubernetes follows a particular release schedule for future releases. I see dates for old releases but don't see anything about following a certain schedule for future releases. If anyone has anything to provide that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

SIG release owns the releases.The typical [patch release](https://github.com/kubernetes/sig-release/blob/master/releases/patch-releases.md) cadence tends to be 3 to 4 weeks. It is commonly a bit faster (1 to 2 weeks) for the earliest patch releases after a 1.X minor release. Critical bug fixes may cause a more immediate release outside of the normal cadence. We also aim to not make releases during major holiday periods

Major/ Minor release happens 4 times in a year. Release timelines of each release can be tracked [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/sig-release/tree/master/releases).